# Почему циклы пропускают scanf()?

Tags: c

имеется такой код, например:

```
char input;
scanf("%c", &input);
if(input != '[') {
    printf("Nespravny vstup.\n"); 
    return 0;
} else {
    while(1) {
        scanf("%c", &input);
        printf("%c", input);
        printf("prohod\n");
        if (input==']') 
            break;          
    }
}
```

Теоретически, при таких входных данных:

```
[ 2 ]
```

мы должны получить вот такие выходные данные:

```
2prohod
]prohod
```

но мы получаем:

```
[

prohod
2prohod

prohod
]prohod
```

выглядит так, будто оно заходит в цикл игнорируя `scanf`, с, почему-то, пустым  значением проходит по циклу, а только потом считывает `scnaf`.

Я пробовал по разному, даже ставил `scanf` в `while()`, однако оно никак  не хочет сначала считывать `scanf`, а только потом делать все остальное.

Я даже добавлял `input2`, однако даже если в начале цикла  стоит `scanf("%c", &input2)`, то оно все равно сначала  делает проверки  и проходит по всему циклу, а потом уже возвращается к `scanf`.

Как мне добиться ожидаемой работы программы?

Comment: это концы строк

Comment: А символ `\n` кто учитывать будет? Вы его сами, своими руками вводили с клавиатуры. Если бы вы ввели `[2]` - было бы другое дело. Но вы ввели именно `[\n2\n]\n`, как сами же и написали в вопросе. Почему вас тогда удивляет наличие символа `\n` во входе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это концы строк.

```
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%c",&input);
        if (input != '\n')
        {
            printf("%c",input);
            printf("prohod\n");
            if (input==']') break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: что значит концы строк? то один элемент типа чар откуда у него может быть конец строки?

Comment: @МитрофанШевцов В Ваших входных данных - что находится между `[` и `2`?

Comment: ааааа все, понял, спасибо

Comment: я же enter нажимаю

Comment: @МитрофанШевцов Точно. Это и есть `'\n'`.